# How to separate duplicate records based on a different column using conditional statements

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a table with two columns and want to filter all the unique values from column 1 based on a conditional statement from column 2.

I have a table `tblSchoolID` with the a column `SUID` and `Contact_Type`.

The `SUID` column has duplicates that are needed to be removed based on the value of the `Contact_Type`. The conditional statement for the `Contact_Type` column is  `1.0 > 2.0 > 4.0 > every other number`. (See example below)

I'm new to MS Access and am having a hard time learning how to implement conditional statements.

```
# What I have
SUID    Contact_Type
15565966    2.0
15565966    0.0
14737063    4.0
14737063    1.0
14737063    0.0
14737063    2.0
14737063    0.0
16737094    0.0
16737094    0.0
16737094    4.0
```

```
# What I need
SUID    Contact_Type
15565966    2.0
14737063    1.0
16737094    4.0
```

I'm using Microsoft Access 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `group by suid` and a little trick to get the minimum `contact_type`:

```
select
  suid,
  min(iif(contact_type = '0.0', '5.0', contact_type )) as con_type
from tblSchoolID
group by suid
```

Results:

```
suid        con_type
14737063    1.0
15565966    2.0
16737094    4.0
```

Comment: What if the minimum non-zero value of `contact_type` is greater than 5?

Comment: The OP mentions: *every other number*, so I guess they are equally treated. If not this needs clarification. Anyway the requirement is not 100% clear since there could be values like 10.0 and then the solution would need to treat the values as numbers.

Comment: In my case they are equal treated.

Comment: Curious, How could you extend the case if you have additional columns? Would you just use ```Group By tblSchoolID.Column3```?

Comment: Based on the condition: `1.0 > 2.0 > 4.0 > every other number` what this code does is get the minimum value of `contact_type` for each `suid`. If there are other columns too and the requirement is the same, then the above query should be joined to the table to fetch the other columns of the row with the minimum value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming concatype is a string  and is always formateed  as  x.y 
you could try using min(contact_type) group by SUID for all the value different from '0.0'

```
select SUID,  min(contact_type) contact_type
from my_table  
where contact_type <> '0.0'
group by SUID
```